# Convert different date formats to a given unique date format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

I have different date formats present as strings those are:

```
[ "2018-06-22",
"June 22, 2018",
"12/15/2017",
"12-24-2015" ]
```

I want to convert them into a single yyyy-mm-dd ("2018-06-22") format. I can split and then do the reformatting but I am looking for a more better way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module `dateutil` does exactly what you need:

```
import dateutil.parser

dates = [ "2018-06-22",
"June 22, 2018",
"12/15/2017",
"12-24-2015" ]

for date in dates:
    print(dateutil.parser.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

OUTPUT:

> 2018-06-22
>   2018-06-22
>   2017-12-15
>   2015-12-24

You can have a look at the [module](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#), or directly install it:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

formatters should be the same as [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).