# Handling a column with dates and missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following code to estimate profit from buy and sell price of crypto token.

```
import pandas as pd


# Read text file into pandas DataFrame
# --------------------------------------
df = pd.read_csv("crypto.txt", comment="#", skip_blank_lines=True, delim_whitespace=True).dropna()

# Display DataFrame
# -----------------
print(df)
print()

# Replace commas in number
# --------------------------------------
df['BuyPrice'] = df['BuyPrice'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df['SellPrice'] = df['SellPrice'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

df['Profit'] = df.SellPrice - df.BuyPrice

# Sort BuyPrice column in ascending way
# --------------------------------------
df = df.sort_values('BuyPrice', ignore_index=True)
#df = df.sort_values('BuyPrice').reset_index(drop=True)
print()


# Sum all the numerical values and create a 'Total' row
# -----------------------------------------------------
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)

# Replace NaN by empty space
# ---------------------------
df = df.fillna('')


df = df.rename({'BuyPrice': 'Buy Price', 'SellPrice': 'Sell Price'}, axis=1)

# Display Final DataFrame
# -----------------
print(df)
```

Now the output does only show the rows with sensible entries in the 'Date' column. I get

```
       Coin BuyPrice SellPrice     Size           Date
1  1INCH    2,520      3180       10     23-10-2021
3   SHIB      500       450  200,000     27-10-2021
4    DOT     1650      2500        1  June 01, 2021


        Coin  Buy Price  Sell Price      Size           Date  Profit
0       SHIB      500.0       450.0  200000.0     27-10-2021   -50.0
1        DOT     1650.0      2500.0       1.0  June 01, 2021   850.0
2      1INCH     2520.0      3180.0      10.0     23-10-2021   660.0
Total            4670.0      6130.0  200011.0                 1460.0
```

Clearly, we can see the rows without dates have been ignored. How could one tackle this issue? How can `Pandas` understand they are dates?

`crypto.txt` file contains:

```
Coin        BuyPrice       SellPrice      Size        Date
#---        ---------       ----------    ----     -----------

ADA         1,580            1,600             1            NA


1INCH       2,520            3180         10         23-10-2021


SHIB        261.6           450         200,000          NA 
SHIB        500             450         200,000       27-10-2021 


DOT         1650            2500           1          "June 01, 2021"
```

It seems I couldn't write the last row and column entry within single inverted commas. Is it possible to convert all the dates in one single kind of format (say  , )?

Comment: this should help you for the date format change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206973/convert-different-date-formats-to-a-given-unique-date-format-in-python

Comment: you seem to be using the "dropna" function while reading the text file, try runnning without dropna

Comment: @PreciXon Oops! I used to think `dropna` works for `NaN` and `NaT`,  wasn't aware that `NA` is also taken care of. Thanks.